# Schottky diode: voltage on anode side

Tags: diodes, schottky

I was trying to power my Raspberry Pi Pico through a Schottky diode [CUS10S30](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/CUS10S30_datasheet_en_20140407.pdf?did=14077&prodName=CUS10S30) according to this schematic:
[image]

The weird thing is that when Pico is powered via USB and nothing is coming from an external supply I can still measure the same voltage on the anode side of the diode, which is completely unexpected, because I expected diodes to only allow voltage in a single direction.

If I replace `CUS10S30` with [1N5819](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/2818/MOTOROLA/1N5819.html) which is also a Schottky diode I can measure voltage only on a cathode side, and there is no voltage on anode side which is consistent with my understanding of how diodes work.

I tried 3 different CUS10S30 (completely new) and all of them allowed voltage in both directions. Are they all faulty or is there something else going on?

Comment: Strange. You have a tiny amount of leakage backwards so if your impedance in the other end is super high, you may see some voltage. Add 1 mA of dummy load and see if it goes away? Anything else in the schematic which may leak across the diode? Otherwise broken it fake component?

Comment: What do you mean with "no voltage"? How exactly are you measuring it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schottky diodes have a lot of reverse leakage. Your meter probably has 10M input impedance, so you only need 0.5 uA of leakage to get 5 V at the meter.

In the datasheet, there is a graph of leakage current at various temperatures and reverse voltages. Your case is off the graph, since the voltage across the diode is small. But you can see that 0.5 uA is reasonable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5Krs5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, that would explain it.
In my case reverse leakage was enough to keep my latch circuit open when Raspberry pi was plugged in: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/633394/unstable-latching-circuit/633415#633415
Switching to 1N5819 solved the issue for now, but I was wondering if I can fix it with CUS10S30.
Would putting a resistor of let's say 100k on the anode side prevent the leakage?

Comment: Also, I tried a bunch of random diodes and I also see the same behavior, my multi-meter shows voltage on both sides when anode is not connected to anything.

Comment: @Leonti Once you connect your voltmeter the anode **is** connected to something. Current will flow through the diode and your meter. Some non-zero voltage is likely to be seen.